# Trigger ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound instead of returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I am implementing vanity url for user URL:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users
match 'u/:login' => 'users#show', :as => :main_user

# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.where(:login => params[:login]).first
  end
end
```

Usually if we use `@user = User.find(params[:id])`, it would return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, which then redirects to `500` or `404` (not sure which one would be redirected to, but that's not important).

But in the case above, it would just return `@user = nil` and continue rendering `show` action. How can I code it in a way it works the same like searching for `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.first!` [(Docs)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first-21) to raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error in case no record could be found.

```
@user = User.where(:login => params[:login]).first!
```

Comment: Awesome answer ! Thanks !